# Unable to see timer job

Tags: feature, feature-activation, solution-deployment, feature-receiver, feature-dependency

I have created a custom timer job, which contains a feature. I have successfully activated the feature on my web application, but it does not show up under the job definitions.

Feature.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" Title="TaskLogger Feature2" ActivateOnDefault="FALSE" AlwaysForceInstall="TRUE" Id="ea2fc2aa-ff41-467b-abf8-89b5ad528857" ReceiverAssembly="TaskLogger, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=97b008c1d4b6e697" ReceiverClass="TaskLogger.Features.Feature2.Feature2EventReceiver" Scope="WebApplication"></Feature>
```

In the ULS logs I am seeing the below error. Note that the deployment target is the GAC though.

> Failed to load receiver assembly "TaskLogger, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=97b008c1d4b6e697" for feature
>   "TaskLogger_Feature2" (ID: ea2fc2aa-ff41-467b-abf8-89b5ad528857).:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'TaskLogger, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=97b008c1d4b6e697' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.  File name: 'TaskLogger,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=97b008c1d4b6e697'
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName,
>   String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
>   Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)     at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)     at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)     at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)     at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureReceiver.LoadAssembly(String
>   assemblyName)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.get_ReceiverObject()
>   WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.  To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.  Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging.  To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

I have checked the version and public key token and here's the output:

> Version = 1.0.0.0 Public Key Token = Microsoft (R) .NET Framework
>   Strong Name Utility  Version 4.0.30319.17929 Copyright (c) Microsoft
>   Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Public key token is `97b008c1d4b6e697`

Essentially what I am doing is this:

```
  SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                    {
                        SPWebApplication webapplication = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication;
                        if (webapplication.Properties.Contains("SiteURL")) webapplication.Properties.Remove("SiteURL");
                        webapplication.Properties.Add("SiteURL", "mysite");
                        webapplication.Update();
                        foreach (SPJobDefinition job in webapplication.JobDefinitions)
                        {
                            if (job.Name == TASK_LOGGER_JOB_NAME) job.Delete();
                        }

                        // install the job
                        CSAtimerJob taskLoggerJob = new CSAtimerJob(TASK_LOGGER_JOB_NAME, webapplication);

                        SPDailySchedule schedule = new SPDailySchedule();
                        schedule.BeginHour = 01;
                        schedule.BeginMinute = 00;
                        schedule.BeginSecond = 00;
                        schedule.EndHour = 01;
                        schedule.EndMinute = 01;
                        schedule.EndSecond = 00;

                        taskLoggerJob.Schedule = schedule;
                        taskLoggerJob.Update();

                    });
```

What can resolve this issue?

Many thanks!

Comment: It would greatly help if you also post the xml code accompanying this as well.  Most likely, it is a syntax error within this part.

Comment: Have you checked GAC if same assembly is present with same version and publickeytoken?

Comment: Hi Aanchal, It's stored in the folder "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\TaskLogger\v4.0_1.0.0.0__97b008c1d4b6e697". I checked the version and it is 1.0.0.0. PUblic Key Token is 151
176
8
193
212
182
230
151

Comment: I'm not sure if you need this for your code, but are you using

    <ElementManifests></ElementManifests>

in your code?

Comment: This is not the case Brandon.

Answer (score 0):

im currently doing a timerJob and its working fine!

Firstly your dll in the assembly should be either in the webapp bin folder if specified or more than likely should be in the global gac folder:

> C:/windows/assembly

next job is goto services.msc

> start -> run -> services.msc

goto sharepoint timer and restart the service so the timer job in central admin picks up the timerjob!

why in the global gac (assembly) folder? well you set it as webapplication level but unless you have stated a specific web app in your manifest for feature than sharepoint would set your wsp as global making your dll global within the assembly folder.

the path you given:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\TaskLogger\v4.0_1.0.0.0__97b008c1d4b6‌​e697

that is for ms applications not custom development apps for sharepoint!

**EDIT**

Just noticed a mistake by me! sorry didnt realise your using .net 4.0. so its in the correct place..... but you noted that within the folder it has the id of:

PUblicKeyToken = 151 176 8 193 212 182 230 151

but in the error its:

PublicKeyToken=97b008c1d4b6e697"

**EDIT**

in your project for your feature what is the deployment target? it should be set to global assembly cache!

Comment: Very bizarre. I have restarted the service and still nothing!

Comment: is the dll in the correct place tho? C:/windows/assembly, the issue is that it cant find the assembly which should be in that folder!

Comment: just noticed that you are doing it in the correct place but the publick key is wrong>?

Comment: how are you deploying the timerjob?

Comment: Through Visual Studio > Build Solution and then Deploy Solution.

Comment: just ammended my answer! check the last edit!

Comment: it is deployed to the global assembly cache..

Comment: this might be able to solve your issue http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/104020/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-dll-or-one-of-its-dependencies-access-is-deni/104162#104162